# The image file attachment is getting displayed as blank in Report Portal

Tags: postman, multipartform-data, reportportal

I have been trying to post a log with an image attached on report portal through postman. The image does gets uploaded, but it shows up as blank, and you cannot really see the image.

[image]

I'm adding the image in the request body in base64 format. Here's the body:

```
--HereGoes
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json_request_part"
Content-Type: application/json

[
    {
    "file": {
      "name": "test.png"
    },
    "launchUuid": "a02bf1c3-b5c0-4209-b57a-34a48deaf266",
    "itemId": "287e26f1-7386-4ce6-b61d-c7c14eb6129d",
    "itemUuid": "287e26f1-7386-4ce6-b61d-c7c14eb6129d",
    "level": "FATAL",
    "message": "custom",
    "uuid": "90",
    "time": "2019-11-15T14:35:55.006Z"
    }
]

--HereGoes
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.png"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<image in base64>
--HereGoes--
```

and the headers:

[image]

I'm not sure why the images won't show. Is there anything wrong with the body? How do get the images to show up as this:

[image]

Help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you image is not a 'PNG'. You also specified some redundant fields: `itemId` and `uuid`, please leave it blank.

Here is my request, which works perfectly:

```
POST /api/v1/default_personal/log HTTP/1.1
Host: http://localhost:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Authorization: Bearer uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json_request_part"

[
    {
    "file": {
      "name": "linus.png"
    },
    "launchUuid": "4a0e6613-5b93-449a-9dd2-9e1f9fce71f7",
    "itemUuid": "6f7d9d33-c6d4-49a4-b9d8-c269f288cf20",
    "level": "FATAL",
    "message": "custom",
    "time": "2020-11-11T14:35:55.006Z"
    }
]
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="linus.png"
Content-Type: image/png

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

How it looks in Postman:
[image: Common postman request view]

[image: JSON part]

[image: RP view]

Comment: When I use the form-data on postman to send the request, it works fine [IMG1](https://i.imgur.com/GHwTrTr.png) [IMG2](https://i.imgur.com/MAu4Git.png). It only doesn't work when I use the raw text in the body like above. I tested this with multiple different PNG files, and I got the same result for all of them.

Comment: @Ritzies, I bet it's not a RP problem, but rather how postman and other tools send requests. The standard has very tight restrictions on format and line delimiters, a single incorrect character and the whole request will be thrown away without any processing. So I would not recommend you to send raw data as you described.